# Не могу найти оптимальную структуру базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть данные по товару(количество товаров более 20к).

[image: Пример данных по товару]

Хочу организовать хранение, но не могу определиться со структурой. Сейчас  каждый товар в отдельной таблице и отдельно есть таблица в которой хранятся все названия этих таблиц.

Как лучше организовать базу данных?

Comment: https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/rukovodstvo-po-razrabotke-struktury-i-proektirovaniyu-bazy-dannyh.html

Comment: структура делается под требования предметной области к данным, в нормальной форме (это термин). Тем более на маленьких базах, как у вас. Из вопроса мне непонятно, что именно вам нужно хранить и что такое "уникальные временные рамки", так что пример привести не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё же лучше занести все эти данные в одну таблицу и добавить колонку `id товара`:

| item_id | date | price | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/2023 | 123 | 100500 |

А в "таблице с таблицами" пусть будут вот эти вот `id` товаров, а не названия таблиц.